# What is the level cap in Overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

Is there a max level I can hit after a certain point in Overwatch? I know some players have been saying there is no level cap, but it seems like there are certain icons that get upgraded as you level up.

What is the level cap in Overwatch?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

## There is no level cap.

There is a level exp cap, that scales until you hit level 20:

| Current Level | XP needed for next level |
| --- | --- |
| Level 1 | 1500 |
| Level 2 | 3000 |
| Level 3 | 4500 |
| Level 4 | 6000 |
| Level 5 | 7500 |
| Level 6 | 8500 |
| Level 7 | 9500 |
| Level 8 | 10500 |
| Level 9 | 11500 |
| Level 10 | 12500 |
| Level 11 | 13500 |
| Level 12 | 14500 |
| Level 13 | 15500 |
| Level 14 | 16500 |
| Level 15 | 17500 |
| Level 16 | 18500 |
| Level 17 | 19000 |
| Level 18 | 19500 |
| Level 19 | 20000 |

As of a [recent update](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20752015856?page=1#post-3), every level past level 20 now only requires 20,000 exp to reach the next rank, and this is consistent even after "prestiging".  So once you hit Level 100, then reset back to level 1, but with a new prestige border icon, you will still need 20k exp to get to the next level, and so on.

New portrait borders are given every 10 levels, starting at 1, 11, 21, 31, etc.

[image]

After you hit level 100, you "prestige" and reset your level to 1, but gain a new portrait border. This happens every time you hit level 100 again.

[image]

At level 1890, or approximately your 18th "prestige" and at level 90, you will finally gain the last portrait border which appears gold and although you can continue prestiging over and over again your profile border will no longer change.

[image]

Comment: http://overwatch.wiki.fextralife.com/Progression+System it seems you like posting and answering questions that are addressed in the wiki too

Comment: This answer has additional information not in that wiki article, including everything regarding prestige.

Comment: The levels are actually wrong, you get the new portaits at 11, 21,31, etc. Not 10, 20 ,30

Comment: When you reset to level 1 does exp needed to get to the next level reset as well?

Comment: @txteclipse Yeah it does. Faster loot boxes :)

Comment: Note that as of [the Nov 7, 2016 patch](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/blog/20335231#patchnotes) the level exp cap was reduced to 20k and no longer resets upon prestige.

Comment: You should probably include the silver portraits that come before gold